# RestSharp JSON List Deseralization

Tags: json, restsharp

I launched this code:

```
var responseSection = client.Execute<List<SectionResponse>>(requestSection);
```

The response I should get:

```
[
    {"SectionId":644852,"Name":"GDTC-MOBL-01-15W","Description":{"Text":"","Html":""},"Enrollments":[]},
    {"SectionId":644853,"Name":"GDTC-MOBL-02-15W","Description":{"Text":"","Html":""},"Enrollments":[]}
]
```

The groups of my data classes:

```
public class SectionResponse
{
    public List<SectionList> sectionList { get; set; }

}
public class SectionList
{
    public int SectionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Description_t Description { get; set; }
    public List<Enrollments_t> Enrollments { get; set; }
}
public class Description_t 
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Html { get; set; }
}
public class Enrollments_t
{

}
```

The problem is it attempts twice (two lists) but each request returns null data.
What should I do to get data?

Thanks in advance,

Phillip

Comment: The issue is with `List<>` deserialization. Use `Array` instaed of `List<>`

Comment: I tried it out with array but it still returns null...

Comment: I tried List<> in a different way and it works. Thanks for giving me help @dbvega!!

Answer (score 0):

You're saying you want a list of `SectionResponse`s, which itself contains a list, so basically you're saying you want a list of lists, which doesn't match the response.

Try either this:

```
var responseSection = client.Execute<SectionResponse>(requestSection);
```

or this:

```
var responseSection = client.Execute<List<SectionList>>(requestSection);
```

Comment: I've already solved it in the exactly same way as yours but thanks, though